# Zend Framework - Using custom functions in Forms

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have MyForm extending Zend_Form, with init() doing regular job.
In this init() I also need to use a function to apply some transformation on some element values. Basically, get values from db -> custom transformation function -> apply them to form element.

I can put this custom function inside the form itself, but it's a general one and it will be reused by other forms.

Question: what is the best way to do this? I'm reading that helpers are associated more with views, and plugins with controllers. Is there a nice and easy way to get in the form the functionality of a custom function?
(something as helpers in symfony - just a bunch of functions)

Thanks.

p.s. this custom function is not a validator or so.

Comment: You could create a subclass of Zend_Form which contains the methods you need in your forms in library/YourName/Form...

Comment: More or less I could extend zend_form with an intermediate form (which will contain all the extra methods) and then extend all my classes based on that. But not quite happy with this approach. Probably will be better to just define a custom class with different extra methods and use it because I don't want to relate it only to forms. Thanks anyway.